# How to make maven versions:use-latest-versions step up import scoped entry in dependencyManagement?

Tags: maven

We use the maven versions plugin to keep our versions up to date by regularly mvn versions:use-latest-versions. In our poms we have an import scoped dependency to another POM that looks like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.company.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-third-party-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When we run mvn versions:use-latest-versions all our dependencies (and other entries in dependencyManagement) get stepped up except this one. Is there a way to get the versions plugin to step up this kind of entry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does work when you put the version of the import-scoped dependency in a property, and use the `versions:update-properties` goal.

Your example pom would then look like this:

```
<properties>
  <my.dependency.version>0.0.1</my.dependency.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.company.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-third-party-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${my.dependency.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you be hitting one of the problems mentioned in the [FAQ](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/faq.html#repo-metadata)?

To rephrase it here, is the artifact which is not getting stepped a local artifact, which is not deployed to a repository manager?  If so, you can resolve this by setting up a repository manager.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the artifact is deployed to a repository manager (Nexus). Hence that should not be the problem.